# Close open divs when opening a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeout, slidetoggle

I am trying to make a menu, but I am having a problem closing menu's that are open when a new one is opened.

I have tried `hide()` but it doesn't seem to work in all instances, here is my code before I have tried any closing methods.

I want only 1 of these 3 functions to be opened at any one time.

When one is opened - any that are already opened should reverse whatever they opened.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sk4m2w2d/1/)

```
//Open/close filters pack menu
$('#filters__menu--show').click(function () {
    $('#filters__menu').slideToggle('750',"swing", function () {
    });
});
//Open/close stickers pack menu
$('#stickers__menu--show').click(function () {
    $('#stickers__section').slideToggle('750',"swing", function () {
    });
});
//draw row + menu open
$('#draw__menu--show').click(function () {
    $('#draw__colors').slideToggle('750',"swing", function () {
    });
    //when draw is open close primary save/restart
    $("#done").fadeOut('750');
    $("#restart").fadeOut('750');
    $("#app__menu").fadeOut('750');
    $("#draw__menu").fadeIn('750');
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is when a new menu is opened, the other menu's are closed / everything they've open is reversed.

I am having particular issues with #draw__menu--show as it does slideToggles and fadeOut other elements.

Is hide() the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Can you also post your html?

Comment: Give all the menus a common class. Then you can use `$(".className").hide();` to hide all the other menus before showing the current menu.

Comment: @Barmar ... and `$(this).show();` to show the current one!

Comment: @Armin I'll try and simplify the HTML and post it

Comment: Yes, or `slideOpen()` if you want animation.

Comment: I thought something like that @Barmar but nowhere near as elegant as what you guys suggest, however it gave me issues with the fadeOut's as they need to be fadeIn - so slideOpen doesn't solve that, that's where my main issue was :)

Comment: You can use whatever function you want to hide and show them. `hide()/show()`, `fadeOut()/fadeIn()`, `slideUp()/slideDown()`, etc.

Comment: @Armin added jsfiddle :)

Comment: @GoldenGonaz you should post the entire [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce three boolean variables: isFiltersOpen, isStickersOpen, isDrawMenuOpen. Initialize them as false. In the callback of each, set the corresponding one to opposite of itself. eg. `isFilterOpen=!isFilterOpen`.

Then call slideToggle again for each of the two OTHER elements. In the callback of the inner slideToggle, make sure to reverse the boolean. So for example, this would be the code for slideToggle for filters_menu:

```
$('#filters__menu--show').click(function () {
    $('#filters__menu').slideToggle('750',"swing", function () {
     isFilterOpen=!isFilterOpen;
     if(isStickersOpen){
     $('#stickers__section').slideToggle('750',"swing", function () {
      isStickersOpen=!isStickersOpen;
     }
    );
    }
     if(isDrawMenuOpen){
     $('#draw__colors').slideToggle('750',"swing", function () {
      isDrawMenuOpen=!isDrawMenuOpen;
     }
    );
    }
});
})
```

Do that for each one. To make it more elegant, you can wrap some of the code in a function

Answer (score 0):

You can do as @Barmar suggested. Add a common class for all elements you want to close on click, and then add closing effect (`hide()` or `slideUp` or...). You can test few to see which one fits your vision the best. Here is an example (I am using `slideUp()` to keep an animation, but if you want without animation you can use `hide()`): https://jsfiddle.net/sk4m2w2d/2/